# Is "Case Record Type" in "Email-to-Case" supported by the metadata API?

Tags: metadata-api, record-type

In the Salesforce org UI, there is the option of setting the `Case Record Type` in the `Case settings`. Here is a screenshot of it being set to the `Inquiry` Record Type:

[image]

Is this setting supported by the metadata API? I ask this because workbench only retrieved the following from the `Case.settings` file:

```
        <enableE2CSourceTracking>true</enableE2CSourceTracking>
        <enableEmailToCase>true</enableEmailToCase>
        <enableHtmlEmail>false</enableHtmlEmail>
        <enableOnDemandEmailToCase>false</enableOnDemandEmailToCase>
        <enableThreadIDInBody>true</enableThreadIDInBody>
        <enableThreadIDInSubject>true</enableThreadIDInSubject>
        <notifyOwnerOnNewCaseEmail>false</notifyOwnerOnNewCaseEmail>
        <preQuoteSignature>false</preQuoteSignature>
        <routingAddresses>
            <addressType>EmailToCase</addressType>
            <caseOrigin>Phone</caseOrigin>
            <casePriority>Medium</casePriority>
            <createTask>true</createTask>
            <emailAddress>random@test.com</emailAddress>
            <isVerified>false</isVerified>
            <routingName>Test</routingName>
            <saveEmailHeaders>false</saveEmailHeaders>
            <taskStatus>Waiting on someone else</taskStatus>
        </routingAddresses>
    </emailToCase>
```

And there was nothing referencing the `Inquiry` metadata type.

Comment: Per [Metadata API doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_casesettings.htm) the answer appears to be NO

Comment: It's definitely not in the `<routingaddresses>` node(s) of the `Case.settings` file, and I can't find anywhere else it's specified (like on the Record Type itself). The Case Owner is also unavailable.